# Php verify data in text box

Tags: php, wordpress, text, format

Im creating a wordpress website that will allow me to search for car registration plates and im struggling to create php code for it. Currently no code has been written so can't upload code to here.

Im just wondering how I can get the "Enter car reg number" textbox to only accept text in the format of '**** ***' e.g BR32 8TU and it bring an error message if format was not adhered to stating that correct format has not been followed and to retry.

Thanks and apologies if its not worded well

DW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a pattern attribute in your form input field and make it a required field.

```html
<form>
<input type="text" name="rego" pattern="[a-zA-Z\d]{4} [a-zA-Z\d]{3}" placeholder="XXXX XXX" title="Must be 4 alphanumeric, space, 3 alphanumeric" required>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

You can test this solution in my runnable snippet.  The submission will be halted if the value doesn't qualify.

Comment: @Iloveitall Have I solved your issue?  If so, do you know how to award the green tick?  If not, please give me some feedback so that I can adjust my answer.  All pages deserve to be resolved.